# Oracle connection to a specific schema and print existence

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I manage to connect the database and retrieve data but im trying to retrieve data from a specific schema with no success.
what i am trying to get is all tables printed in this schema.
I didn't found any solution online, and im frustrated.

###### AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'current_schema'###

def check():

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('bla blaa', 'bla bla', 
service_name='Cbla bla')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='blaa', password='blaa', dsn=blaa)
c = conn.cursor()
c.current_schema= 'abc'
try:
 sql = "select table_name from all_tables where regexp_like(table_name, :tn, 'i')"
 searchstr = 'student'

 c.execute(sql, (searchstr,))
 for tabname, in c:
  print(tabname)

except:
 print('not working');
```

Comment: setting `current_schema` - even if it worked - would only change the default schema used to fully qualify a table name. it does _not_ change the user/schema to which you are connected, or your access privileges. the `all_tables` view will only list tables to which the `blah` user that you initially connected to has access. setting `current_schema` will not have any effect on the content of that view.

Answer (score 0):

current_schema is related to the connection, not the cursor, that's why you have this error. But, the comment from @pmdba is still valid. What you'll see in all_tables depend on your connected user not your current schema. If you se current_schema to user X, and you have not rights on X's objects you want see them in all_tables.